# Jetty 6 - VirtualHosts - SSL Certificates

Tags: jetty, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have several virtualhosts configured on a single Jetty instance.  I would like to also have unique SSL Certificates for each virtualhost.

Can I do this?

My understanding is that the call to add a connector can only be made inside a Server configuration meaning that there is only 1 SSL certificate that can be used.

Walter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517336/apache-name-virtual-host-with-ssl may be informative. Also, look for similar questions on serverfault.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I'd like to keep everything within Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case, I need to have SSL setup on another port / ip address which I presently do not have.  So, for the time being, I can only have 1 certificate.